# extract max and min values from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, max, min

I have the following code:

```
content = {}

f = open("input.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    key, value = line.split()
    content[key] = value
    price_values = content.values()
    max_price = max(price_values)
    min_price = min(price_values)
print(content)
```

my input file is:

```
A31 149.99
B31 49.99
A41 179.99
F31 169.99
A35 179.99
A44 169.99
```

any ideas why min max is not working here?

Comment: What's the error? Unexpected output?

Comment: apologies, the output is returning: max_price 49.99
min_price 149.99

Comment: You've presumably printed out `content.values()` to see that it's what you expected, yes?

Comment: @jarmod, yes, I did. outside of this code. I also checked it in the variable explorer

Answer (score 2):

Reason was you were trying to find `min` and `max` on string. Turn them into floats first. Also I suggest take your min and max out of the loop.

```
content = {}
f = open("test.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    key, value = line.split()
    content[key] = float(value)
    price_values = content.values()
max_price = max(price_values)
min_price = min(price_values)
print(max_price,min_price)
```

output

```
{'A31': 149.99, 'B31': 49.99, 'A41': 179.99, 'F31': 169.99, 'A35': 179.99, 'A44': 169.99}
179.99 49.99
```

Here is a shortened version of your code.
Note, it does not speed your code up in anyway. In fact, correct me if I'm wrong but it probably also slows down your code. I just post it because it's nice to look at.

```
print(max({line.split()[0]:float(line.split()[1]) for line in open("test.txt", "r")}.values()),min({line.split()[0]:float(line.split()[1]) for line in open("test.txt", "r")}.values()))
```

Comment: Ah, oops. I just glanced at the first line (and noticed that you didn't print content at all) which is why I brought it up. Sorry

Comment: @buddybob. thank you. that is much cleaner. does the [0] and [1] designate the key and value?

Answer (score 0):

I'd write the code this way:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    content = {
        k: float(v)
        for line in f
        for k, v in line.split()
    }

price_values = content.values()
max_price = max(price_values)
min_price = min(price_values)
print(max_price,min_price)
```

Comment: line is not defined

Comment: I think it's because of the new lines that are in the definition of content. Try removing those newlines